# WSO2 ESB making SAP BAPI adapter calls

Tags: adapter, wso2-esb, bapi

I need to make a SAP BAPI call from ESB. I followed the steps provided in the below link:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/SAP+Integration

Can someone please provide me a solution for BAPI calls? (the above link works for IDoc but I am unable to make BAPI calls)

Answer (score 0):

This link (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/SAP+Integration) is the right one.

Just below "Configuring WSO2 SAP Adapter", you can find 2 tabs : the 1st and default one is "Configure with IDoc adapter" and the 2nd one is "Configure with BAPI adapter"

You can also have a look to https://www.yenlo.com/blog/topic/wso2-sap-adapter